# w3c html validation error - Section lacks heading: where h2 available in nested element

Tags: html, w3c-validation

Am trying to write valid html by following w3c standards. But getting warning on below code as `Section lacks heading. Consider using h2-h6 elements to add identifying headings to all sections`. But I have used `<h2>` in my section, then why am I getting this and how can I overcome?

```
<section id="section1">
  <article class="container">
    <h2>Some heading</h2>
  </article>
</section>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `<article>` contains a heading, but your `<section>` does not, because your `<h2>` is associated with your `<article>`, not your `<section>`.

If your `<section>` is just a generic container and not an actual distinct section of articles in your page, it should be a `<div>` instead, or a `<main>` if it's the *only* container in your page (but judging by the section ID it's probably safe to assume it isn't). Alternatively, your `<article>` should be a `<div>` instead as "container" is a rather oddly generic class name for such an element.

Note that sections missing headers is not an error but a warning; you are free to leave your `<section>` without a heading, it will just look strange in the document outline. Nevertheless, the warning is there to indicate that you may have either left out a heading, or you may be misusing sectioning elements.